# Python - seaborn add grit to multiple plots

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a question. How to add a grid for plots?

```
fix, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, figsize = (10, 4))
sns.boxplot(data = file, x = 'Diag', y = 'radius', hue = 'Diag', ax = axs[0])
sns.histplot(data = file, x = 'radius', hue = 'Diag', alpha = 0.6, ax = axs[1])
```

I tried "sns.axes_style('whitegrid')", but it doesn't work with plt.subplots

```
fix, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, figsize = (10, 4))
with sns.axes_style('whitegrid'):
    sns.boxplot(data = file, x = 'Diag', y = 'radius', hue = 'Diag', ax = axs[0])
    sns.histplot(data = file, x = 'radius', hue = 'Diag', alpha = 0.6, ax = axs[1])
```

[image]

Comment: You need to set the style before creating the plots. So, before `fig, axs = plt.subplots(...)`

Comment: You can also loop through the axes: `for ax in axs.flat: ax.grid(True)`